# Change url in inframe tags

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem like the following. I embed a chart in my site with inframre tags with . My website has a option tag. How can I change url 1 in an iframe to url2 when choosing option 2, url3 when choosing option 3. A solution would be very grateful.
Example :

```
  <iframe src="url1"></iframe>
    <select id "select">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
```

I found a very simple solution. This is my solution.

```
<iframe src="url1" id="urlFrame"></iframe>
<select id="tuyencap" onchange="changeValue(this)">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeValue(){
    var tuyencap = document.getElementById("tuyencap").value;
  alert(tuyencap)
   if (tuyencap ==1){
       document.getElementById('urlFrame').src="url1";
       }
    else if (tuyencap ==2){
         document.getElementById('urlFrame').src="url2";

        }
   else if (tuyencap ==3){
         document.getElementById('urlFrame').src="url3";

        }
   else if (tuyencap ==4){
         document.getElementById('urlFrame').src="url4";

        }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hello. You have to write what you tried before and users will say you why your codes didn't work.

Comment: you have to write some javascript when change event fires on the select you have. Do you use jquery? Or plain javascript?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt@AliSheikhpour . But I wrote this question because I did not have any solution to this problem. Please understand me.

Comment: @Lelio Faieta  I use javascript when change event on the select. If you need me to show you the code

Comment: if you ask us to help you to fix your code you have to show us it, no?

Comment: @LelioFaieta I added my code. Still javascript but it's too long to put up here. If you want I will put up. I have nothing to hide since it's just a simple javascript.

Comment: you should be posting your "relevant" code for the question not "all" your code ;-). Anyway see if my answer can fit your need

Answer (score 1):

use `onchange` for your `select` element

```
<iframe src="url1" id="urlFrame"></iframe>
<select id = "select" onchange="changeValue(this)">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
function changeValue(element){
    var value = element.value;
    document.getElementById('urlFrame').src = value;
}
```

**Note**
The value of your options should be the URL you intend to use so instead of:

```
<option value="1">1</option>
```

I expect you should have something like:

```
<option value="http://google.com">1</option>
```

**EDIT 1**

You can use the `innerHTML` also but I don't think it's good user experience

```
<option value="1">http://google.com</option>
```

__

```
var value = element.innerHTML;
document.getElementById('urlFrame').src = value;
```

**EDIT 2**

Like @LelioFaieta suggested you can use the `data.*` attribute:

```
<option data-url="http://google.com" value="1">1</option>
```

Javascript:

```
function changeValue(element){
    var urlSelect = element.dataset.url;
    document.getElementById('urlFrame').src = urlSelect;
}
```

Comment: This must work fine. I suggest the same and insist on defining the URL in <option value="">1</option>

Comment: Thanks for your solution but i can not set value = url, because the value is also used in another javascript. Is there any other solution?

Comment: use a data attribute for each option. Something like data-url="url1"

Comment: @hungtrinh you can also use the `innerHTML`. See my edit. However using the `innerHTML` is not good user experience

Comment: Thanks for your solution but ai can not set <option value="1">http://google.com</option>. Because The name of the option is fixed by value example:                                                                
  <select id="select">
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="3l">Opel</option>
  <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>

Comment: are you using jquery? If you are you can use the `data` attribute like @LelioFaieta suggested. You'll use Jquery to get the data attribute value for selected option

Comment: @AyoK you can do it with plain javascript. Jquery is just a library that helps you to write js in an easier way but has no extra features from plain js. See my answer for details

Comment: hmm. Nice @LelioFaieta

Comment: @AyoK Thanks for your support. I found a very simple solution. Please allow sharing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with data attribute if you need.

```
<iframe src="url1" id="urlFrame"></iframe>
<select id="select" onchange="changeValue(this)">
  <option value="1" data-url="url1">1</option>
  <option value="2" data-url="url2">2</option>
  <option value="3" data-url="url3">3</option>
  <option value="4" data-url="url4">4</option>
</select>

function changeValue(){
   var x = document.getElementById("select");
   var myoption = x.options[x.selectedIndex];
   var urlSelect = myoption.dataset.addr;
   alert('urlSelect = '+urlSelect);
   document.getElementById('urlFrame').src = urlSelect;
}
```

The dataset attribute is the attribute that read all the data attributes from your option tag.

Comment: Quick question: so that means the `data` attribute value for the selected option will be assigned to the parent select `tag` ?

Comment: it works exactly like the value attribute or any other data-* you wll put. The select will have the value of the selected option

Comment: Hi @LelioFaieta. Thank you for your support. It seems that is what I need. But I tried and it does not seem to work. Please review see where I am wrong. I edited above.

Comment: @Lelio Faineta  I add code aler(urlSelect), and it looks like your javascript was wrong. It does not get url.

Comment: @hungtrinh i have updated my answer with a slightly different javascrip. Please note that id declaration in the select was missing a =

Comment: Hi @LelioFaieta. Thank you for your enthusiams. But  when i alert('urlSelect = '+urlSelect) the result is still "undefined".

Comment: this is working correctly for me. Are you using a html5 doctype? data attributes are valid starting from html5 only

Comment: @LelioFaieta I use html5. I updated the html page above.

Comment: That’s not html5 at all. Wrong header for 5

Comment: @LelioFaieta I have tried many ways but failed. Please show me where I am wrong. Do you have a successful experiment? If so show me?

Comment: @LeioFaineta Thanks for your support. I found a very simple solution. Please allow sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check the code below,it's working absolutely fine. You just need to change path as per your requrement

```
 <html>
 <head>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 </head>
     <iframe height="800px" width="800px" 
     src="http://cdns2.freepik.com/free-photo/facebook-logo_318-49940.jpg" 
     id="imageToSwap" class="profile"></iframe>
          <select onchange="$('#imageToSwap').attr('src', 
          this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value="http://cdns2.freepik.com/free-photo/facebook-
         logo_318-49940.jpg" selected>Facebook</option>
        <option value="http://cdns2.freepik.com/free-photo/twitter-logo_318-
        40459.jpg">Twitter</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution

Comment: Hi @roopesh. Your solution also uses value = url :(

Comment: Yes,as we are using option list then we need to have value to get access of it. Let me know,what exactly in your mind.